# CNMutableContact not accepting new phone number property

Tags: swift, macos

I'm making a simple contact creation program for os x, but have hit a barrier when it comes to adding a phone number to a new CNMutableContact. The following code snippet works fine on iOS, but throws `Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subside=0x0)` when run for os x:

```
import Contacts

let contact = CNMutableContact()

contact.givenName = "John"
contact.familyName = "Doe"
contact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelHome, value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue:"(555) 555-5555"))]

let store = CNContactStore()
let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
saveRequest.addContact(contact, toContainerWithIdentifier:nil)
try! store.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest)
```

All the documentation I've found online, including on Apple's developer website, matches my syntax exactly, but removing the line that creates the phone number fixes the problem and allows the contact to be created.

I'm still pretty new to swift, so any basic explanation or solution to this issue and why it's only affecting os x would be greatly appreciated.